# C# code to check Java script disabled in browser

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i am having a application in which java script is must. but i am facing problem when at any client browser has java script disabled. i want a code using which i can check the browsers java script enabled/ disabled property so that the user cannot login until he enables javascript. can anyone help me in this code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply have the "log in" button disabled by default and have it enabled by JavaScript when the document is loaded.

Also put a message saying the JavaScript is disabled on a page and make it visible by default. Upon document load, hide the message. Alternatively, use the `<noscript>` tag.

Comment: way to think out of the box  :) +1

Comment: but i need to give user a message about java script disable. otherwise he might not know what to do.

Comment: I'd also have a message directing a user to enable JS, which would be disabled by JS on page load

Comment: @Sumit Gupta: have the message show up by default, and then hide it as you show the login button with JS.

Comment: @roman m: thanks for code. it helped me a lot. easy n nice solution.

Comment: +1 @Sumit accept the answer, this is the way it should be done. Checking at the server side isn't reliable. As mentioned in the answer, use the <noscript> tag for whatever message you want to show to the user when javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/CheckJavascriptEnabled.aspx)